# Deeplink: How to redirect user to a website when app is not installed instead of playstore

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, backend, deep-linking

How do we simulate this behaviour?

```
When the app is installed -> redirect to the app
When not installed -> Redirect to some webpage.
```

If the app is not installed, the default behaviour is redirecting the user to the play store (Using Google's dynamic link).

Is it possible to do it via Google's dynamic link?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect to the app store from a deep link if the app is not installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53597261/how-to-redirect-to-the-app-store-from-a-deep-link-if-the-app-is-not-installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem. There are two fields: `androidFallbackLink`  and `iosFallbackLink`  in google dynamic links for this exact issue.
Attaching the documentation link for the same: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener

Comment: as dynamic links will be deprecated, any other way of achieving this?